# Trying to call constructor, receiving "no matching function call" compilation error

Tags: c++

I am currently working on creating a program called OOP head of students. the program is supposed to open up a file, read the information, send the information through classes and and properly display the results. I am currently creating information manually from main as a test.

Here is my code:

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

#include "School_Academics.h"

using namespace std;


int main(){
    School_Academics n;
     Name name = Name("jack", "lopez");
     Address address = Address("123 some street", "Apt. A", "somecity", "somestate","somezipcode");
    Date dob = Date("01", "12", "1990");//date of birth
    Date dog = Date("07", "11", "2014");//date of graduation  
    School_Academics acad = School_Academics("3.64", "25", dog);
    cout<<n.getStudent()<<endl;
    Student n2 = Student(name, address, dob, acad);
    cout<<n2.getStudent();

}
```

**Student.h**

```
#ifndef STUDENT_H_INCLUDED
#define STUDENT_H_INCLUDED

#include "Address.h"
#include "School_Academics.h"
#include "Name.h"
#include "Date.h"

using namespace std;

class Student{
    private:
        Name name;
        Address address;
        Date dob;
        School_Academics acad;

    public:
        Student();
        Student(Name name, Address address, Date dob, School_Academics acad);
        string getStudent();

};
#endif // STUDENT_H_INCLUDED
```

**Student.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

Student::Student(){
    name = Name("","");
    address = Address("","","","","");
    dob = Date("0","0","0");
    acad = School_Academics("0","0","0");
}
Student::Student(Name name, Address address, Date dob, School_Academics acad){
    Student::name = name;
    Student::address = address;
    Student::dob = dob;
    Student::acad = acad;

}

string Student::getStudent(){
    name.getName();
    address.getAddress();
    acad.getSchool_Academics();
    dob.getDate();
}
```

**School_Academics.cpp**

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

#include "School_Academics.h"

School_Academics::School_Academics(){
    GPA = "0";
    credits = "0";
    Date DOG = Date("0","0","0");
}

School_Academics:: School_Academics(string GPA, string credits, Date DOG){
    School_Academics::GPA = GPA;
    School_Academics::credits = credits;
    School_Academics::DOG = DOG;
}


string School_Academics::getSchool_Academics(){
    stringstream ss;
    ss <<"School Academics: GPA: "<<GPA<<" credits: "<<credits<<" Graduate: "<<DOG.getDate()<<endl;
    return ss.str();
}
```

**Date.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <sstream>

#include "Date.h"

using namespace std;

Date::Date(){
    day = "0";
    month = "0";
    year = "0";
}

Date::Date(string day, string month, string year){
    Date::day = day;
    Date::month = month;
    Date::year = year;
}

string Date::getDate(){
    stringstream ss;
    ss <<"Date: "<< day << "/" << month << "/" << year << endl;
    return ss.str();
}
```

**The Problem:**

I am currently having problems sending information from the `main.cpp` and passing it through the `Student.cpp` and getting the `class Student{};` to get the information from the `Date.cpp`.

**Error Received:**

`|13|error: no matching function for call to 'School_Academics::School_Academics(const char [1], const char [1], const char [1])'|`

If you could please help me resolve the error. Thank you in advance.

Comment: it is, its in School_Academics.cpp

Comment: `acad = School_Academics("0","0","0")` is being invoked, where the last parameter is supposed to be a `Date`, not a string. Unless `Date` has a conversion constructor from a single string (and it doesn't), that isn't going to work. `School_Academics("0","0", Date())` will probably get you further along.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just tried implementing `Date()` as a parameter and it still gave me the same error.

Comment: You could tell because thats what the declaration of class Date declares the constructor to take. Its right there in the header. Use the Source, Luke.

Comment: @cahuizar You already told it that the third parameter would be using a date, when you declared `School_Academics::School_Academics(string GPA, string credits, Date DOG)`. It's up to you to stick to your own rules and pass a `Date` it when you call it. You told the compiler the third parameter should be a `Date`, but then you passed it a string, and it rightly complained.

Comment: Should GPA, credits, day, month, year ... be strings?

Comment: @JasonC I understand what your telling me, but how exactly would I send a date variable? In otherwords, how would i crete the data variable without it being a string? thanks for your help.

Comment: @drescherjm since I am not doing anything with the variables but print them, I thought it would be easier to simply have them as strings.

Comment: @cahuizar The answer to that is right there in `Date.cpp`. Use the constructor you've provided. E.g. `Date d = Date("6", "3", "2015");` and now you have a `Date` named `d`, which you can pass around as needed. You have `dob` right there already, in fact.

Comment: You may want to have a read of http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/, it should at least get you on the right track, and will certainly give you the tools you need to answer the questions you've been asking here.

Comment: I mean, you're *already doing this correctly in main.cpp*, so do it exactly the same way as that.

Comment: @WhozCraig I just tried doing it that way and this happens... http://i.imgur.com/sM4bk78.png

Comment: @cahuizar considerably further along than not even compiling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error comes from your student ctor where you have the following

```
acad = School_Academics("0","0","0");
```

The `School_Academics` ctor with 3 char is not defined. This cause the error.

You probably meant to pass the date you created just above:

```
Student::Student(){
    name = Name("","");
    address = Address("","","","","");
    dob = Date("0","0","0");
    acad = School_Academics("0","0",dob);
    // or acad = School_Academics("0","0",date());
}
```

Comment: if I do this it complains that dob was not initialized. `|14|error: 'dob' was not declared in this scope|`

Comment: @cahuizar do you have exactly the same constructor as the one I put above? or did you remove the line where you create dob ? dob should be defined right before acad

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/sM4bk78.png  thats the error that i get when I compile, I have tried it with the two ways that you provided.

Comment: @cahuizar Your image doesn't represent a compilation error. But maybe your problem is coming from the function `Student::getStudent()` which doesn't return the string. You should do the same things as you did in `string Date::getDate()` and `string School_Academics::getSchool_Academics()`

Comment: omg I didn't even realize that I hadn't returned anything. Thank You so much. I would upvote you but can't lol.